# Quoting only strings in csvhelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I understand that I can quote all fields in [csvhelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) using the likes of the following but how does one quote all string fields only in Filehelpers you have the data annotation

Does csv helper have something like this

> [Quoted]
>   public string mystring {get;set;}

```
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
    };

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
        csv.WriteRecords(records);

        writer.ToString().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/981), adding that feature was considered and rejected as being an edge case.

To achieve what you are after, you could write your own converter to deal with those fields as needed. If you do, take care of the note about `Configuration.QuoteNoFields = true` in that Github issue.

There is an example type converter [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion/)